# In Rails 4 and FactoryGirl, how do I override the base factory's "after(:build)" method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback, factory

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 with FactoryGirl.  I have this factory for my users

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    …
  factory :user do
    after(:build) do |user, vars|
      print "in main user after build.\n"
      def user.publish
        # and here you can stub method response if you need
      end
    end

    …

    trait :with_callbacks do
      after(:build) do |user, vars|
        print "after build my user\n"
      end

      …
    end
```

I wanted to override my base “after(:build)” method, so I created the trait “with_callbacks.”  But when I call my factory with my traits

```
create(:user, :my_user)
```

It seems like both “after(:build)” methods are getting called based on the output …

```
after build my user
in main user after build.
```

Is there a way to rig things so that I can override the base factory’s “after(:build)” method?

Comment: each of the `before/after` statements add the callback to a chain, and callbacks in the trait are run in addition to the base ones, so the behavior is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but another option would be to use a transient variable (called `ignore` in FactoryBot versions < 5.0) to control the behavior, which can be overwritten in a trait.

Something like:

```
  transient do # use `ignore` in factory bot < 5.0
    with_callback_behavior { false }
  end

  after(:build) do |user, vars|
    if vars.with_callback_behavior
      puts "behavior for trait after build."
    else
      puts "behavior for main main after build."
    end
  end
  trait :with_callbacks do
    with_callback_behavior { true }
  end
```

Of course, this means that

```rb
build :user, :with_callbacks
#=> "behavior for trait after build."
```

is the same as

```rb
build :user, with_callback_behavior: true
#=> "behavior for trait after build."
```